# Fading with jquery

Tags: jquery, random, transition, fade

I'm trying to add a nice transition to the randomized workds in this function and I can't seem to get it to work, bear in mind I'm a newbie at this. If someone could explain how I could add a fading effect between the words I would really appreciate it!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
words = ['ASS-KICKING','MIND-BLOWING','AWESOME','SWEET'];
$(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    var thisWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
    $("#container").text(thisWord);
  },3000);
});
});
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein) and [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout) for this

And use the ready function once like,

```
words = ['ASS-KICKING','MIND-BLOWING','AWESOME','SWEET'];
$(function() {
   setInterval(function() {
      var thisWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
      $("#container").fadeIn(1500).text(thisWord).fadeOut(1500);
   },3000);
});
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/eKE8k/1/

**Updated** Change the `time delay` with the use of callbacks

```
words = ['ASS-KICKING','MIND-BLOWING','AWESOME','SWEET'];
$(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    var thisWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
      $("#container").fadeOut(1000,function(){$(this).text(thisWord).fadeIn(1000);});
  },5000);
});
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/eKE8k/2/

Comment: As a result, you can see the text being abruptly replaced, then it fades out and immediately fades back in. You'll need to use a callback for proper timing.

Answer (score 0):

firstofall you don't need two `document.ready` function there.remove one..and for effect you can use [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) or [`slideDown`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) or `animation()`

try this (using fadeIn)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 words = ['ASS-KICKING','MIND-BLOWING','AWESOME','SWEET'];

 setInterval(function() {
   var thisWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
  $("#container").hide().text(thisWord).fadeIn('slow');
 },3000);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery provides three fading methods: [.fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/), [.fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/), [.fadeToggle](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/). These all take similar parameters. One of these parameters is a callback that is invoked once the animation has completed.

Your code should look something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    words = ['ASS-KICKING','MIND-BLOWING','AWESOME','SWEET'];

    setInterval(function() {
        $('#container').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            var thisWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
            $('#container').text(thisWord).fadeIn('slow');
        });
    },3000);
});
```